# Java Loops and UIs

Tags: java, strings, user-interface

I've always found coding UIs in Java very inefficient, and hopefully this is because of my misunderstanding. Here's a great example.

I have a UI class which is returning the String "Hours", which is effectively going to be a CSV file containing opening and closing hours of a business, Monday through Sunday. Each of these values come from individual combo boxes. So to build this String, I was curious - is there any possible way to improve it through, say, loops or some kind of recursive function?

Otherwise it's incredibly difficult to read. Any suggestions how to improve this disgusting code?

```
String hours = cbMondayStart.getItemAt(cbMondayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbMondayFinish.getItemAt(cbMondayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbTuesdayStart.getItemAt(cbTuesdayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbTuesdayStart.getItemAt(cbTuesdayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbTuesdayFinish.getItemAt(cbTuesdayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbWednesdayStart.getItemAt(cbWednesdayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbWednesdayFinish.getItemAt(cbWednesdayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbThursdayStart.getItemAt(cbThursdayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbThursdayFinish.getItemAt(cbThursdayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbFridayStart.getItemAt(cbFridayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbFridayFinish.getItemAt(cbFridayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbSaturdayStart.getItemAt(cbSaturdayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbSaturdayFinish.getItemAt(cbSaturdayFinish.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbSundayStart.getItemAt(cbSundayStart.getSelectedIndex()) + "," +
    cbSundayFinish.getItemAt(cbSundayFinish.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: How about putting the references of the elements in a list when you create them, and using a loop?

Comment: `String hours = comboBoxes.stream().map(c -> String.valueOf(c.getSelectedIndex()).collect(Collectors.joining(",");`

Comment: Rule 1 of programming: don't blame the compiler. Obvious parallel: don't blame the programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for repeated code and pull it out:

```
Stream.of(cbMondayStart, cbMondayFinish, cbTuesdayStart, cbTuesdayFinish, ...)
    .map(e -> e.getItemAt(e.getSelectedIndex()))
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Works a charm, had this code in the end for anyone else looking for a finale:

String hours = Stream
     .of(cbMondayStart, cbMondayFinish, cbTuesdayStart,
       cbTuesdayFinish, cbWednesdayStart,
       cbWednesdayFinish, cbThursdayStart,
       cbThursdayFinish, cbFridayStart, cbFridayFinish,
       cbSaturdayStart, cbSaturdayFinish, cbSundayStart,
       cbSundayFinish)
     .map(element -> element.getItemAt(element
       .getSelectedIndex())).map(String::valueOf)
     .collect(Collectors.joining(","));